# Uppercase related objects in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, case, cakephp-3.0, firebird

I'm using CakePHP with Firebird database with plugin [cakephp-firebird-driver](https://github.com/mbamarante/cakephp-firebird-driver/), and I need convert the related object keys to uppercase.

Controller:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Fazendas']
];
```

Result:

```
{
   "LOTES": [
    {
        "ID": 12,
        "LOTE": "\u003C 150 Kg",
        "FAIXA_INICIAL": "0.000000",
        "FAIXA_FINAL": "150.000000",
        "FAZENDA_ID": 5,
        "fazenda": {
            "ID": 5,
            "NOME": "FAZENDA 1",
            "LOGRADOURO": null,
            "INSCRICAO_ESTADUAL": null,
            "CEP": null,
            "TELEFONE": null,
            "CNPJ": null,
            "PROPRIETARIO_ID": null,
            "CIDADE_ID": null
        }
    }
}
```

But the "fazenda" keeps in lowercase.

How I can do this?

Comment: Without any knowledge of CakePHP, is this automatically generated from the database metadata? Is `fazenda` a table or column name, and is it possible it is actually also stored as a lowercase name in the database metadata (because it was created as a quoted object name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "fazenda" is an association and by [convention](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) in the entity it is converted to lower cased + underscored by default.

[Change your property name for that assoc.](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#associations-linking-tables-together)

Example taken from the docs (read them!):

```
$this->belongsTo('Authors', [
    'className' => 'Publishing.Authors',
    'foreignKey' => 'authorid',
    'propertyName' => 'person'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be your your relation is `hasOne` or `belongsTo` then you may add a property
 `'propertyName' => 'FAZENDA'` in relation array.